# I am replacing my countertop and sink. How do I choose a new sink that fits my existing plumbing?

Tags: kitchens, sink

I am going to replace my countertop and sink, but the installer wants me to buy the sink first and then he will make the appropriate cut outs for it.  Then I will need a plumber to install it.

1. How do I know how to buy the right size sink so that my plumbing wont need major work?
2. Or, should I just buy whatever kitchen sink I like best and then have my plumber make adjustments?

Here are some pictures: 
[image: image description here]
[image]

Comment: You may want to also consider the cabinet space when choosing the new sink. I ran into a problem where my new sink was too deep, and I had to modify the cabinet to make space for it.  It's a little disheartening when you get a beautiful new sink, drop it in, and it doesn't go all the way down.  Check for cross members, or anything else that may get in the way of the new sink.  Also keep in mind you'll need space to mount the anchor brackets that hold the sink down, so you'll have to consider the cabinet width and depth.

Comment: I removed your price request since that can be very variable an usually is too broad for SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plumbing for a sink is fairly standardized.  The only thing you need to worry about is if you get a significantly deeper sink which pushes you below your drain line.  Since you're also replacing the counter, there's no need to worry about finding a sink that will cover your existing sink area.

Edit: Looking at the picture, I think you've got a good several inches lower that you can go before you will run into any issues with the drain.  I believe I see flex lines which means the plumber doesn't even need to solder any connections.  Note, because you have electrical and plumbing so close down there, please be sure that this outlet is on a GFCI breaker.

Answer (score 5):

You've got loads of space in there and nothing out of the ordinary, so unless you're considering some type of commercial-style extra deep sink don't sweat it.

It's also worth mentioning that all that plumbing that connects the drain and disposal to the stub-out on the back wall just fits together with built-in compression fittings you can tighten by hand.  Even if you've never done plumbing before I bet you could handle connecting this back up yourself.  The parts are readily available at any box store and might set you back $20, maybe less depending on what parts you can reuse.  For tools you'd just need an adjustable wrench to remove and reattach the supply lines, a pair of channel-lock pliers to attach the drain basket to the bottom of the sink, and a sharp utility knife in case you need to cut any of the thin-walled drain tubing to length.

Comment: DIY tip: You should consider installing the faucet into the sink before installing the sink into the counter.  Doing it in the other order can have side effects including headache, irritability, tiredness, back and neck pain, scraped knuckles, and the urge to use regrettable words.